# Can't Render base64 file using FileResponse or StreamingHttpResponse, works using HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, file, base64, httpresponse

I am saving my file in base64 in database and then trying to render it using Django view.

```
file_obj = AttachmentData.objects.filter(id=file_id)
file_data = base64.b64decode(file_obj.attachment_file)
bytes_out = BytesIO()
bytes_out.write(file_obj)
response = HttpResponse(string_out.getvalue(),content_type=email_file_obj.mime_type)
response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename={}".format(name)
return response
```

This code works fine, but When file is large then i need to use StreamingHttpResponse or FileResponse. The problem is these responses need file object as parameter. To create file i need to save it which i don't want as it will consume up my disk space.

```
temp_file_obj = open(file_obj.file_name, 'wb')
temp_file_obj.write(file_data)
temp_file_obj.close()
response = FileResponse(open(file_obj.file_name, 'rb'), content_type=email_file_obj.mime_type)
```

I need a solution so that i send file without saving file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass a true file object to a `StreamingHttpResponse`, you can yield the data itself as the parameter. The documentation provides [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-csv/#streaming-large-csv-files) example, where they show passing a large CSV file as a response. You can do something similar with the data you have stored as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just send data like that when it's base64 :

```
file_obj = AttachmentData.objects.filter(id=file_id)
file_data = base64.b64decode(file_obj.attachment_file)
return file_data
```